# Thevenin and resistance problem

Tags: thevenin

[image]

I had a problem finding the Thevenin equivalent resistance of this circuit. If anyone could help me, I would be very thankful.

Comment: It's going to be weird.  Are you sure that the current in I1 is nine times the current in R1, and in the opposite direction (more or less)?  You can either try to do this with clever Thevenin substitutions, or you can just do it with brute-force Nodal analysis and algebra -- unless your prof is insisting on doing it with Thevenin substitutions, I'd go with nodal, algebra, and a sledge hammer.

Comment: Find the open-circuit voltage, the short-circuit current, and use Ohm's Law.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! This appears to be a homework question. As such, you need to show us your work so far, and explain which part of the question you're having trouble with. For future reference: Homework questions on EE.SE enjoy/suffer a special treatment. We don't provide complete answers, we only provide hints or Socratic questions, and only when you have demonstrated sufficient effort of your own. Otherwise, we would be doing you a disservice, and getting swamped by homework questions at the same time. See also [here](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/5120/7036).

Comment: Your circuit is flawed. As @TimWescott said: with A-B being open your currents can NOT flow that way. As such you can not solve it with any method.

Comment: @Oldfart: D'oh!  I didn't see that.  Yes, the circuit as it stands asserts that 1 = -9, which is a bit difficult to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

This is really quite straightforward. Here are some hints:

1. Combine R1 and R3 together. Components in series can be in any order, and splitting them like that is just intended to confuse you.
2. What is the current through R2? (general expression)
3. Specifically, what is the current through R2 when A and B are open? When they are shorted?